# How pattern use to .split() parenthesis in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, parentheses

I have to split a string from file text but i don't know which pattern use.
Second Line of the file.txt i have something like this:

```
([ )]
```

I thought of doing the split and then inserting the brackets in an array such that with indexes it can go back to the type of parenthesis and print them (closed or open)

I have already tried some pattern like `split("[\\(||//)]")` but it doesn't work.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Esercizio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));


        String s =(String) b.readLine();
        String s2 =(String) b.readLine();
        String[] a = s2.split("[\\(||//)]");
                String w_open=a[0];
        String w_close=a[1];


             System.out.println(w_open);
             ...etc
```

Now i have :
With 0 and 1 i expected the two open brackets [ and (

`w_open=a[0]` output "nothing" i expected ( or [

`w_open=a[1]` output [ i expecte an open bracket so is correct

With 2 and 3 i expected the two closed brackets ] and )

`w_close=a[2]` output  ] //is correct

`w_close=a[3]` output Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Esercizio1.main(Esercizio1.java:16)
```

Comment: No idea what you want sorry. Paste example input and require output.

Comment: Since both `()` parenthesis and `[]` square brackets are special characters in regex, they all need to be escaped, so to search for the literal text `([ )]` you need regex ``\(\[ \)\]``, which as a Java string literal means ``"\\(\\[ \\)\\]"``. Or you could just call `Pattern.quote("([ )]")`, which actually creates the regex ``\Q([ )]\E``, aka ``"\\Q([ )]\\E"``

Comment: With .split("\\(\\[ \\)\\]");i have this error for any index i insert on array: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Esercizio1.main(Esercizio1.java:14)